# Django: internal linking of dynamic sections

Tags: javascript, html, django

Utilizing a {% x, y in zebras %} loop,

1. I am dynamically inserting multiple tables with similar data onto a page.
2. As the list can get really long, (eg table 100), I hope to provide the user a way to 
   get to the table he wants to view quickly and easily
3. I am currently trying ( with no success ) the use of the innerpage anchors. 
         -  
         -  link to table3

I welcome any better, efficient or user friendly solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you consider paginating zebras and having a navigation autocomplete for the user to "go to" a particular table ?

Comment: I have not considered that option yet. can I please have more information on it?

Comment: An idea would be to make a navigation autocomplete like facebook. Here's an [example with autocomplete.js that comes with django-autocomplete-light](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/navigation.html). You might want to start by something else like the video demo of django-autocomplete-light thought, to see if that would work for you before doing anything. Probably django-selectable or plain jquery-ui could do the trick thought.